# jQuery each() complete callback function

Tags: jquery, callback, each

I'm trying to scan all stylesheets within DOM using following each() function

```
$("link").each(function(){
    $.get($(this).attr('href'), function() {
        // Some Code...
    });
});
```

This code works fine but I want to get callback to know that **All Stylsheets** have been scanned & Run another function thereafter. Is it possible to achieve this ?

Comment: What do you mean by scanning stylesheets?

Comment: I'm doing some cssText function to look through css files.

Comment: And you should stop doing it !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create an array of [`$.Deferred`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) objects:

```
var jqXHRs = $("link").map(function() {
  return $.get($(this).attr('href'), function () {
    // Some code...
  });
});
```

And then pass them to [`.when()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) and use the [`done()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) callback:

```
$.when.apply(null, jqXHRs.get()).done(
  function() {
    // All done
  }
);
```

Comment: Wow, a lot better than the hideousness I was going to answer...  +1 :)

Comment: this answer should deserve more upvotes, anyway: imho this should be the only (elegant) way to perform this specific task in jQuery.

Comment: @João could I ask you why are you passing `jqXHRs.get()` instead of just `jqXHRs`?

Comment: Fabrizio, i was going to mention that. It needs to be jqXHRs as the request have already been run, passing jqXHRs will cause the get requests to run a second time.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you loading each stylesheet a second time (they already loaded in your page once) over AJAX when you could just interrogate them via the `document.styleSheets` API?

```
for (var i in document.styleSheets) {
    /* code here involving cssText or whatever */
}
```

Since this approach would constitute a synchronous operation, you wouldn't need a callback - you would just put your 'callback' code right after the loop.

Comment: I'm accessing iframe stylesheets.

Comment: Right, so `framename.document.styleSheets`

Comment: My original code looks something like this http://jsfiddle.net/jvnVA/2/ How do I call my code within API you specified ? My Javascript knowledge is bad..

Comment: Here's the API: http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/stylesheet.shtml. Also, I did an article on this some months back that takes you through it step by step - [part 1](http://www.mitya.co.uk/blog/2011/Dec/Being-Firebug-pt-reading-CSS-Javascript-194) and [part 2](http://www.mitya.co.uk/blog/2011/Dec/Being-Firebug-pt-which-rules-which-elements-195).

Comment: Thanks for the Informative Links. I'm digging into your tutorials.

Comment: With your references I have managed to get stylesheets using document.styleSheets API here : http://jsfiddle.net/pLFsb/1/ But for iframe, framename.document.styleSheets doesn't work. I get Undefined Error. Can you shade some more light ?

Comment: Can you set up your Fiddle so it actually demo's the situation you're facing? There's no iframe there. Is the iframe content on the same domain?